# How to remove repeatable keys, key preview of the Android custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

How to remove repeating keys, key preview of Android Custom Keyboard. I used following method to remove key preview of the keys that I want. But that method is not working for repeatable keys. (android:isRepeatable="true") If the key is not repeatable, following method is working.

**delete key xml**

```
<Key android:codes="-5"
        android:keyWidth="13%p"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_key_delete_white"
        android:keyBackground="@color/dark_key_background"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:horizontalGap="3.5%p"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
```

**Input method service Class**

```
@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    if (primaryCode == -1 
            || primaryCode == -5){
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    if(primaryCode == -1 
            || primaryCode == -5){
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Revers setPreviewEnabled flag..

```html
public void onCreate() {

    mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);

}

public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    if (primaryCode==-1||primaryCode==-2||primaryCode==-5||primaryCode==-4){

    } else {
       mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In following example we have two repeatable keys (Space and Delete)

STEP 1: set PreviewEnabled to "false" in onCreateInputView() :

```
kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
```

STEP 2: add following if-else statement in onPress() :

```
public void onPress(int primaryCode) 
{
   if (!(primaryCode==32||primaryCode==Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE))
   {
       kv.setPreviewEnabled(true);
   }
   else
   {
       kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
   }
}
```

STEP 3: set PreviewEnabled to "false" in onRelease() :

```
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) 
{
   kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an answer on this, check it out here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446268/5689605

To put it here,

Here is the modified Keyboard class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
import android.os.Build
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import com.continental.testapplication.utils.dpToPx
import java.lang.reflect.Method

class ModifiedKeyboardView :KeyboardView{
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet):super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr:Int):super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr:Int, defStyleRes:Int):
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    /**
     * Return true, if preview is to be shown, false otherwise. If not implemented,
     * the preview is going to be shown.....
     */
    var keyPreviewIndexListener:((Int)->Boolean) ?= null

    private val findKeyIndicesMethod:Method = KeyboardView::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
            "getKeyIndices",Int::class.java,Int::class.java, (IntArray::class).java).also {
        it.isAccessible = true
    }
    private val previewText:TextView = KeyboardView::class.java.getDeclaredField(
            "mPreviewText").let {
        it.isAccessible = true
        it.get(this) as TextView
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(me: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if(me == null) return super.onTouchEvent(me)
        when(me.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> isPreviewEnabled = true
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val touchX = me.x - paddingLeft
                var touchY = me.y.toInt() - paddingTop
                val verticalCorrection = dpToPx(14f, context)
                if (touchY >= -verticalCorrection)
                    touchY += verticalCorrection.toInt()

                val keyIndex:Int = findKeyIndicesMethod.invoke(this, touchX.toInt(), touchY.toInt(), null) as Int

                    isPreviewEnabled = keyPreviewIndexListener?.invoke(keyIndex)?:true
                    if(!isPreviewEnabled){
                        previewText.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }


            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(me)
    }
}
```

Paste it as is.

Next, in the class where you are manipulating the keyboard,

```
 keyboardView.keyPreviewIndexListener = {
            it != spaceIndex && it != doneIndex && it != deleteIndex && it != `your_custom_index`
        }
```

To find the indexes you can just do the following

```
 doneIndex = keyboardView.keyboard.keys.indexOfFirst {
            it.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE
        }
```

This will prevent the movement. Please append the other solution also.
i.e

```
override fun onPress(primaryCode: Int) {
            Log.e("onPress", primaryCode.toString())
            checkAndActivatePreview(primaryCode)

        }

        override fun onRelease(primaryCode: Int) {
            Log.e("onRelease", primaryCode.toString())
            deactivatePreview()
        }

 private fun checkAndActivatePreview(primaryCode: Int) {
        keyboard.isPreviewEnabled =
                (primaryCode != `your_custom_code`
                && primaryCode != SPACE_KEY_CODE && primaryCode != Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
                && primaryCode != Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If key is repeatable `OnRelease` method will be called as soon as `OnPress` called.
Use this code

```
@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    if (primaryCode == -1 
            || primaryCode == -5){
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
    }else{
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

}
```